# How do you add an annotation at your current location with a button click

Tags: ios, swift3, core-location

So I want to make a button that sets an annotation at your current location. I have all of my map stuff and core location code working it is just the button. Here is my button function code:

```
@IBAction func addAnnotation(_ sender: UIButton) {
    CLLocationManager().startUpdatingLocation()
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    // Set the annotation by the lat and long variables
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
    annotation.title = "User location"
    self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Right now, I When I run this code I get a SIGABRT Error in my AppDelegate.swift. Please Help.

Comment: Have you checked whether `map` is nil?

Comment: In general, it's a good idea to to a bit more troubleshooting before posting. That will help us to help you. In this case you should add a breakpoint a the line CLLocationManager() line. Then step through the code one line at a time until it crashes. Include that information in the question. Also, if it's crashing on the self.map line, then it's probably nil and stepping through the code will also show that in the console (in the self variable section.)

Comment: I restarted my project in Xcode and now it does not crash It just does not work. Does anyone have any Ideas?

Comment: To get good answers, it's important to follow the guidelines of this site (and do a bit more troubleshooting per my above comment). Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)